# How to calculate the absolute central moment of a Binomial distribution?

Tags: binomial-distribution, moments

There is an experiment. The coin is tossed $n$ times with $p = 0.5$. The experiment is repeated $k$ times. I need to calculate the average central moment.

For example, let $n = 5$ and $k = 3$.

$[0, 0, 1, 1, 0], sum = 2, abs(0.5 * n - sum) = 0.5;$

$[1, 1, 1, 0, 0], sum = 3, abs(0.5 * n - sum) = 0.5;$

$[0, 0, 0, 1, 0], sum = 1, abs(0.5 * n - sum) = 1.5;$

averageCentralMoment $= (0.5 + 0.5 + 1.5) / 3 = 0.83$

However, if you repeat the whole experiment many times, the central moment is equal:

averageCentralMoment = $0.94$

How can I calculate the limit for `Average Central Moment` without simulation?

Comment: Your calculations appear to estimate $\mathbb{E}(|pn - X|)$ for a Binomial$(n,p)$ variate $X$. That would be a mean absolute deviation from the mean.  Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @whuber, I guess so. Is there a way to calculate this function without simulation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By induction on $m$ it is straightforward to show that

$$\sum_{k=0}^m \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}(pn-k) = (m+1)\binom{n}{m+1}p^{m+1}(1-p)^{n-m}.$$

For a Binomial variable $X$ with parameters $n$ and $p$, which models the "sum" in the question, the mean absolute deviation from the mean $np$ is

$$\eqalign{
\mathbb{E}\left(|np - X|\right) &= \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor np \rfloor}\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}(np-k) - \sum_{k=\lfloor np \rfloor+1}^n\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}(np-k) \\
&= 2 (1-p)^{n-\lfloor n p\rfloor } p^{\lfloor n p\rfloor +1} (\lfloor n p\rfloor +1) \binom{n}{\lfloor n p\rfloor+1},
}$$

with the last step following from two applications of the first result (together with elementary binomial identities).  The notation "$\lfloor n p \rfloor$" refers to the *floor* of $np$--the greatest integer less than or equal to $np$.

For example, with $n=5$ and $p=1/2$ as in the question, this formula gives

$$2(1-1/2)^{5-2}(1/2)^3(2+1)\binom{5}{3} = \frac{15}{16} = 0.9375.$$